# Jquery draggable not working in chrome/safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a page that uses ajax calls to load product images. The jquery code for drag, drop and clone would not work when in the index.php page so I moved it to the page that gets called to request the products as each product has drag, drop code created for it.

Works fine in FF, even IE but not in Safari or Chrome. Below is the jquery code in load_products.php that gets created when the ajax call is made to load the products.

http://tandyleatherfactory.net/

Anyone have any idea why wouldn't work in Safari?

```
$(function() {$("#concho_4_2").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    zIndex: '1001',
    stop: function(event, ui) 
    {
        offsetElement = $(ui.helper).offset();
        offNewContainer = $('#belts').offset();

        var dataId = $(ui.helper).attr('id');

        ajaxRequest('http://tandyleatherfactory.net/includes/ahah/add_product.php', 'product=4', '#conchos');

        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
        var newId = 'concho_4_2_'+randomnumber;

        $(ui.helper).clone(true).removeAttr('id').attr('id',newId).css("left", offsetElement.left-offNewContainer.left-10).css("top", offsetElement.top-offNewContainer.top-10).appendTo('#belts');                     
        $('#'+newId).draggable();                
    }
});
```

Comment: Log or alert something just before `$('#'+newId).draggable();` to make sure the script is getting that far. I see that in Safari, the cloned element is not getting the `draggable` class.

Comment: Also, there is no need to wrap the `ui.helper`, just use `ui.helper.attr('id')` and also `ui.offset` is provided, no need to use `ui.helper.offset()`

Comment: alert produced nothing, if it was working, the conchos should at least be draggable but they are not, fudgey I made the udpate you suggested.

I copied the draggable code into the index.php page, if you select 1" conchos it is teh first concho.

Not sure what to think.

Even if I mo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the loaded ajax page had  tags wrapping the script tag, removed the tags, presto, works in IE, FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera.

Thanks for your suggestions.